# How to execute a query per db connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm currently doing the following which works but is inefficient since it's calling it before every action

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_intervalstyle
  
  private
  def set_intervalstyle
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SET intervalstyle = iso_8601", "SCHEMA")
  end
end
```

I noticed [here](https://gist.github.com/vollnhals/a7d2ce1c077ae2289056afdf7bba094a) that they're registering this command per connection

```
  alias_method :configure_connection_without_interval, :configure_connection
  define_method :configure_connection do
    configure_connection_without_interval
    execute('SET intervalstyle = iso_8601', 'SCHEMA')
  end
```

Could someone help me figure out how to convert my before_action into something like this? Maybe as an initializer? I'm not sure where to start

Comment: Is this something that can be set server-side? I'm not sure Rails can do it for you out of the box.

Comment: I monkeyed something as an initializer which seems to work but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to override configure_connection


`require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
  def configure_connection
    execute('SET intervalstyle = iso_8601', 'SCHEMA')
  end
end`

Comment: Probably not a great idea, which is why I was asking about server-side settings for defaults like this.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is a good idea but so far this works and hasn't had any side effects

> config/initializers/set_intervalstyle.rb

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
  alias_method :configure_connection_without_interval, :configure_connection

  def configure_connection
    configure_connection_without_interval
    execute('SET intervalstyle = iso_8601', 'SCHEMA')
  end
end
```